# Difference between inlineSourceMap & inlineSources typescript compiler options

Tags: typescript

From the docs:

> **--inlineSourceMap and inlineSources command line options**:
>   --inlineSourceMap causes source map files to be written inline in the generated .js files instead of in a independent .js.map file.
>   --inlineSources allows for additionally inlining the source .ts file into the .js file.

Does this mean the full file sources are written to the outputFile? Why would you want to do this? You can use the sourcemaps to reconstruct the original sources again anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently, typescript sourcemaps' default behavior is to redirect the dev tools to the original source files, instead of including them into the sourcemaps.

This means that without `inlineSourceMap: true`, you are required to serve the original .ts files along with your bundled code.

Setting `inlineSourceMap: true` changes this default behavior to what I would've expected typescript to do out of the box: include the source info into the sourcemaps. This way, you don't need to serve the original source files along with the app bundle.

Comment: I may be confused, but I'd expect that *not* inlining is the default b/c in browser apps for example, you don't want to keep actual production source files as lean as possible for performance. Inlining the source map and original TS into the JS would drastically increase bundle size.

Comment: Regardless of the setting of `inlineSources`, I don't see any TS included anywhere. I only see .js and .map.js files being emitted, and the .js file has a link to the .map.js file at the bottom. Nowhere is there a TS source. Is this answer incorrect? Or does TypeScript have a bug?

Comment: Ah, I was looking in the wrong place. The source is included into the .map.js file. Thanks!